# How to rerun same JavaScript from console everytime a page reloads?

Tags: automation

Suppose there's a webpage `www.example.com` (I don't own it).

I want to run a JavaScript's script on it using Chrome's console every time it is reloaded. The script needs to be same each time.

Example:

I override the `onload` method on that page using console. Then I do some stuff on `example.com` programatically which refreshes it. And I don't want to change that overridden `onload` method when the page reloads.

I want to execute the same code that's inside the overriden `onload` method every time after the page's reload.

I want to do some kind of automation.

Comment: If the automation is about keyboard and mouse emulation, you can do it with extensions. 
But if it does require custom javascript, then your best bet might be an extension like Tampermonkey that allows you to create and run your custom code on page start.